# Checkbox into Array processing

Tags: php, arrays

I have this kind of question. In my form, i got this as a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="access[1]" value="E01">Highway 1<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="access[1][]" value="C001" >&nbsp;C001<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="access[1][]" value="C002" >&nbsp;C002
<br>
<br>
<input id="access[2]" type="checkbox" name="access[2]" value="E03">Highway 2<br><br>
<input id="access[2]" type="checkbox" name="access[2][]" value="XXXX">&nbsp;XXXX
<br>
<br>
<input id="access[3]" type="checkbox" name="access[3]" value="E05">Highway 3<br><br>
<input id="access[3]" type="checkbox" name="access[3][]" value="XXXX">&nbsp;XXXX<br>
<br>
```

And in my PHP code, i got this :

```
foreach ($_POST ["access"] as $id => $subs) {       

    foreach ($subs as $sub) {

        $subcategory = $sub;

        echo "<p>".$id." - ".$subs." - ".$subcategory."</p>";

    }

}
```

The result is somehow like this :

http://s12.postimage.org/f2xi0yz4p/data4.png

The array that you see should be the value from the form right? Like "E01" / "E03" / "E05". How i can make the "Array" word to be as the main category ?

The expected output should be something similar like this :

1 - E01 - C0001
2 - E01 - C0002
3 - E03 - XXXX
4 - E05 - XXXX

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by this? "How i can make the "Array" word to be as the main category ?"

Comment: You can see here :

http://s12.postimage.org/f2xi0yz4p/data4.png

The output is array , i want to make it appeared like "E01" / "E03" as you see from the field as the main category

Comment: You want same output as mentioned in this link or expected output is different??

Comment: I still can't understand what you mean by this "as the main category", is it like some PHP keyword that I'm not aware of? Or just something in your code that you're assuming that we already know?
can you write the expected output?

Comment: Ok,i added the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to rename `access[1]` and `access[2]` to something like: `access[1][id]` `access[2][id]` as `access[1]`/`access[2]` is automatically being converted into an array by the following inputs.

Then you can access those variables:

```
foreach ($_POST ["access"] as $id => $subs) {       

    foreach ($subs as $key=>$sub) {
        if($key!='id'){
            $subcategory = $sub;
            echo "<p>".$id." - ".$subs['id']." - ".$subcategory."</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The code you give exactly what i need. But i do a bit tweaking so that it suite my need. I will update later on the answer.